# Wireless activation key Fn12 does not respond in Hp notebook pavilion g4 2210la

Tags: hp, keyboard-layout

When I press Fn12 this sign appers and nothig happens. How do I make Fn key work properly?

Comment: Please provide your Ubuntu version, might be useful to others

Comment: have you tried enabling it through your BIOS?